# CORS preflight fails with net::err_failed when using localhost but is fine when it's done on IP

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, preflight

The setup is as follows:

- Chrome v106 with "Experimental Web Platform features" enabled in the flags
- Local chrome browser connected to a certain domain, let's call it "remote"
- A local running HTTP listener (.NET Framework) listening to "http://localhost:8850"

When the JS does a http request from "remote" to "http://localhost..." the preflight fails with the net::err_failed error and the following message: "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8850/Data' from origin 'http://remote' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.". I am assuming this is some extra safety implemented in the browser to reduce attacks on local systems

When I change this "localhost" to the actual IP of the local system (both in the http request, and the setup of the http listener server-side) the preflight does go through correctly.

Is there any information on why this works? I would like to get it working with "localhost" as well if that's possible.

This is also not an issue when the special chrome flag is disabled, but I can't find any information on what is included in this change.